# Two rows of data combined into one

Tags: mysql, sql

A beginner in SQL but given the opportunity to create my own database.

So I have a table Invoice with similar reference numbers but different status code numbers.

Table Invoice:

```
Reference     Status Code     Status Date
  10198053           300       08/07/2013 
  10198053           500       08/09/2013
```

I would like the output to show:

Table Invoice:

```
Reference     Status Code    Status Date     Status Date 2
  10198053           300       08/07/2013      08/09/2013
```

Code:

```
select reference r, status Code s, status Date,
case 
     when r=r and s=s (???)
from Table Invoice
```

Comment: What are you trying to show?  In your example you are showing the first Status Code, not the most recent and two Status Dates.  Could there be more Status changes?  If so, how many?  How many do you want to show?  Perhaps a little context would be helpful.  What do the statuses mean?

Comment: There won't be any status changes as I've coded it to just show 300 and 500.  I just want it to show the two status dates side by side.  The status code doesn't need to be there.  I can verify that data.

Comment: You can `JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`) the same table results on different condition, but what if there are more status codes? You can't have variable number of columns. You may try some *string aggregation* then, but I doubt that you really need to struggle for one row result (can't be sure without context).

Comment: There are more status codes but I've narrowed it down to the two.  This is what I came up with after 2 hours of headaches.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDITED**
Try this:

```
SELECT Invoice.reference, MIN(Invoice.statusCode) AS statusCode, MIN(Invoice.statusDate) AS statusDate, MAX(Invoice.statusDate) AS statusDate2
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY Invoice.reference;
```

GroupBy your reference number to get one instance of it on your query. Then use the MIN and MAX function to get the first and last instance of statusDate on a specific reference.

Comment: Even better - haven't used MySQL in some time.  First() and Last() would be nice in TSQL!

Comment: As far as I know FIRST() only works in MS Access.  It does not exist in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you need to see a date for 300 and a date for 500, you could aggregate two columns based on each of those Status_Code:

```
SELECT 
  Reference,
  MIN(CASE WHEN Status_Code = '300' THEN Status_Date ELSE NULL END) AS Status_Date_300,
  MIN(CASE WHEN Status_Code = '500' THEN Status_Date ELSE NULL END) AS Status_Date_500
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY Reference;
```

As is indicated in the comments, this could change depending on the requirements of exactly what you are trying to find - however, this should get you started.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03aba/1) to test the above.

Comment: select t1.reference,t1.status_code,t1.status_date, t2.status_code,t2.status_date
from Invoice t1
join Invoice t2
on t1.reference = t2.reference
where t1.status_code in ('300')
and t2.status_code in ('500')

Comment: Nice - that will work too - few different ways to go about it.  Glad you got it to work.